# How to construct an explicit isomorphism between two special endomorphism rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\Lambda$ be an artin algebra and $M$ a $\Lambda$-module. Let $\Gamma:=\text{End}_\Lambda(M)$ and let $D$ be the standard duality.

> How can you give an explicit isomorphism $\text{End}_\Gamma(M)\cong \text{End}_{{\Gamma}^{\scriptstyle{op}}}(D(M))$?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\text{End}_\Gamma(M)$ is precisely the center of $\Gamma = \text{End}_{\Lambda}(M)$.

Let $\varphi \in \text{End}_{\Gamma}(M)$. Consider $D \varphi: DM \rightarrow DM$. I claim that $D \varphi$ is a $\Gamma^\text{op}$-module homomorphism. Note that given $\psi \in \Gamma$, the action of $\Gamma^{\text{op}}$ on $DM$ is given by $\psi \cdot f := f \circ \psi$ (this makes sense because both $f: M \rightarrow \Lambda$, and $\psi: M \rightarrow M$ are $\Lambda$-linear maps). Now we check

\begin{align*}
D \varphi(\psi \cdot f) &= D\varphi(f \circ \psi) = (f \circ \psi) \circ \varphi  \\ 
&=f \circ (\psi \circ \varphi)
 = f \circ (\varphi \circ \psi) \\
&= (f \circ \varphi) \circ \psi = \psi \cdot (f \circ \varphi) \\ 
&= \psi \cdot D\varphi(f) 
\end{align*}
for every $f \in DM$ and $\psi \in \Gamma$.